# No need to dispose DataContext/ObjectContext in EF?

Tags: entity-framework, repository, repository-pattern, idisposable

Albahari writes in "c# 4.0 in a nutshell":

> >
>   Although DataContext/ObjectContext implement IDisposable, you can (in general)
>   get away without disposing instances. Disposing forces the context’s connection
>   to dispose—but this is usually unnecessary because L2S and EF close connections
>   automatically whenever you finish retrieving results from a query
>   <<

This feels wrong and FxCop also complains if you are not diposing something that is IDisposable.

I have the following repository code:

```
    public abstract class Repository<TEntity> : IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
    { ...
        public void Add(TEntity entity)
    {
        using (var dbContext = this.UnityContainer.Resolve<DbContext>())
        {
            dbContext.Set<TEntity>().Add(entity);
            dbContext.SaveChanges();
        }
    }

    ...

    public virtual IEnumerable<TEntity> Find(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> expression)
    {
       using (var dbContext = this.UnityContainer.Resolve<DbContext>())
       {
           return dbContext.Set<TEntity>().Where(expression).ToList().AsEnumerable();
       }
    }
    ...
```

Note: I do not return IQueryable - lazy loading should not play a role.
Resolve DbContext is configured as PerResolveLifetimeManager.

Is this approach OK or do I need to reconsider this based on Albaharis description?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should always call dispose if class exposes it. The statement claims that EF and L2S close connection whenever they finish operation - as I know the statement is correct but in the same time ADO.NET team also closes connection in `Dispose` method so perhaps there are situations when connection is not closed.

Comment: "You should always call dispose if class exposes it." -- No, not always, see for example [Do I need to dispose of Tasks?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/03/25/10287435.aspx) You don't need to call `Dispose` if `Dispose` does nothing of interest *and* `Dispose` won't be updated in the future to do anything of interest. I cannot tell whether an `ObjectContext`'s `Dispose` does or can do anything useful, so I have no answer to the question, but I don't agree with the reasoning in yours. "so perhaps there are situations when connection is not closed" -- not if you're using it right.

Comment: Thank you Ladislav - I don't like the idea that you can drop the Dispose on Disposables but it seems to be like that in some situations.

Comment: @hvd: In such case it is just abusing of Disposable pattern and another situation where core .NET architecture was broken.

Comment: @hvd: I read the whole article and its all about backward compatibility. `Task` in .NET 4 should still be disposed but in .NET 4.5 it is not needed but to maintain compatibility with existing code (due to inplace upgrade of .NET 4 to 4.5) it still exposes `Dispose` method. That is very specific situation.

Comment: @LadislavMrnka No, that article says not to bother with disposing. Not in .NET 4.5, but not in .NET 4 either: even without .NET 4.5's improvements, disposing isn't worthwhile.

Comment: You should always call Dispose on the context. In some situations it might not do anything, in other situations it will. If Dispose never did anything then there wouldn't be a bunch of code in EntityConnection.Dispose.

Comment: I've never called Disposed on a context and it doesn't appear to have resulted in any problems so I prefer to omit it to avoid boiler plate-y type code.

Comment: yes dude your statement is too categorical. you should always wash your hands after visiting toilet - thats something i'd agree.

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on EF 4.0 ObjectContext (yeah, I know...). I ended up looking at the code in DotPeek, and the dispose just nulls the reference to the connection and a few other things in the ObjectContext class.

When a connection is created (also found through DotPeek) it returns the existing instance. If the connection string is changed, it'll update the connection string for all instances.

That was my take on it at least. Need to look deeper but at first glance, it seems that you can get away with it.

Comment: A little more digging and I found this article. From a guy who talked to the guys that wrote it.

http://blog.jongallant.com/2012/10/do-i-have-to-call-dispose-on-dbcontext.html